# Null pointer exception to check whether a xml have the element or not

Tags: java, xml, dom

My part of code is below see,

```
NodeList nodes=doc.getElementsByTagName("user");
if(nodes.getLength()==0)
system.exit(1);
```

Initially, xml dont have user element.
But, I got an null pointer exception.

How to solve this...
And how do I find the no of nodes even if the nodes doesn't exists initially.
It shud return 0 nodes.
Thank you

Also I checked this....
     NodeList nodes=doc.getElementsByTagName("user");
     if(nodes==null)
     system.exit(1);

Then aldo I got null pointer exception.

Comment: `nodes` value is `null`, when you call the `getLength()` method on it, you get the `NullPointerException`

Comment: I checked the node value is null or not but alsa I got an null pointer exception.